# Creating sub lists with objects of the same attribute from a list using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a Person which looks like:

```
public class Person {
    public string name;
    public int age;
}
```

and I have a method:

```
public List<List<Person>> createPairedList(List<Person> plist){
    List<List<Person>> newList = new List<List<Person>>();

    foreach (Person person in plist)
    {
       bool breaking = false;
       for (int i = 0; i<newList.Count(); i++)
       {
           foreach (Person p in newList[i])
           {
               if (p.age == person.age)
               {
                    newList[i].Add(person);
                    breaking = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (breaking){break;}
        }
        if (!breaking)
        {
            newList.Add(new List<Person>(){person});
        }
    }
    return newList;
}
```

where each item in the sublist has the same age.

So the content would look something like:

```
[{name="bob", age="20"},
{name="billy", age="21"},
{name="bobby", age="20"},
{name="john", age="21"},
{name="george", age="22"}]
```

then after this method it would looke like:

```
[[{name="bob", age="20"},{name="bobby", age="20"}],
[{name="billy", age="21", {name="john", age="21"}}],
[{name="george", age="22"}]]
```

Is there a way to do this using a LINQ expression?

Comment: If you want to group the Person instances by age, ILookup<int, Person> (returned by GroupBy and ToLookup) is probably a better choice than a list. (for example: persons.GroupBy(person => person.age)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var newList = list.GroupBy(p => p.age).Select(p => p.ToList()).ToList();
```

will return `List<List<Person>>` grouped by `age`

Comment: GroupBy returns a collection of IGrouping<int, Person>, not of Person

Comment: @vc74 `list.GroupBy(p => p.age).Select(p => p.ToList())`  will return `IEnumerable<List<Person>>`

Comment: Yes, but then you'll loose the key (age), that's the reason why I believe the OP is more looking for an ILookup than for a list

Comment: @vc74 well it depend on scenario requirements.

Comment: absolutely, but I'm suspecting a lookup might be more an easier solution for this issue